# What brand are these shower faucets?

Tags: shower, trim

How do I know what kind of replacement kit will fit. I am not sure if this is Moen or Delta. [image]

[image]

Comment: Have you begun to disassemble any of the parts? There may be marks on the bottom or inside. Are you simply looking for new trim pieces or to replace the whole faucet. The top faucet, in particular, looks to be from the 70s or 80s, and you might not be able to find trim pieces for it anymore, meaning a full replacement _might_ be in the cards anyway.